# error when building berkley db 4.8.30

Tags: windows, mingw32

```
$ make
./libtool --mode=compile gcc -c -I. -I../dist/..  -O3  ../dist/../rep/rep_auto.c

libtool: compile:  gcc -c -I. -I../dist/.. -O3 ../dist/../rep/rep_auto.c  -DDLL_
EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/rep_auto.o
In file included from ../dist/../rep/rep_auto.c:3:0:
./db_config.h:600:19: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 #define socklen_t int
               ^
../dist/../dbinc/repmgr.h:502:13: note: in expansion of macro 'socklen_t'
 typedef int socklen_t;
         ^
In file included from ./db_int.h:886:0,
             from ../dist/../rep/rep_auto.c:5:
../dist/../dbinc/repmgr.h:502:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
[enabled by default]
typedef int socklen_t;
^
make: *** [rep_auto.lo] Error 1
```

I was using this

```
cd /c/db-4.8.30.NC-mgw/build_unix
sh ../dist/configure --enable-mingw --enable-cxx
make
```

i got this error on make. I am fairly new to software development, so please noob friendly replies are appreciated

I was following this tutorial on compiling dogecoind.exe for windows

```
https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master-1.5/doc/build-msw.md
```

Comment: Are you compiling with the mingw cross-compiler running on Linux as the instructions say? This looks like a config error due to conflicts in header files of mingw on Windows.

Comment: I am on windows 8. I have no idea why do i need to build_unix when I am on windows. But that is what the guide from the dogecoin page says.+ i was able to build it on another windows 8 pc successfully without a problem

Comment: I removed the 'sh' and now run ../dist/configure --enable-mingw --enable-cxx
it seems to be buiding. But shouldn't i be using build_windows rather than build_unix?

Answer (score 2):

I just compile dogecoin on DigitalOcean Linux VPS, Just copying here the steps that i followed during Dogecoin wallet compilation:
Compile Dogecoin Wallet on Ubuntu(4GB Ram60GB SSD Disk):

```
Pre-Install:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libtool autotools-dev autoconf automake
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1++-dev
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1++-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost1.54-all-dev
```

**Clone Dogecoin Repo on server:**

```
1: git clone https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin.git
2: cd dogecoin
```

## 3: ./autogen.sh

```
   Berkely DB (Run following command 1 by one)
```

### REFRENCE: https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md)

```
BITCOIN_ROOT=$(pwd)

# Pick some path to install BDB to, here we create a directory within the   dogecoin directory
BDB_PREFIX="${BITCOIN_ROOT}/db5"
mkdir -p $BDB_PREFIX

# Fetch the source and verify that it is not tampered with
wget 'http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-5.1.29.NC.tar.gz'
echo '08238e59736d1aacdd47cfb8e68684c695516c37f4fbe1b8267dde58dc3a576c  db-5.1.29.NC.tar.gz' | sha256sum -c
# -> db-5.1.29.NC.tar.gz: OK
tar -xzvf db-5.1.29.NC.tar.gz

# Build the library and install to our prefix
cd db-5.1.29.NC/build_unix/
#  Note: Do a static build so that it can be embedded into the executable, instead of having to find a .so at runtime
../dist/configure --enable-cxx --disable-shared --with-pic    --prefix=$BDB_PREFIX
sudo make install

# Configure Dogecoin Core to use our own-built instance of BDB
cd $BITCOIN_ROOT
./configure  LDFLAGS="-L${BDB_PREFIX}/lib/" CPPFLAGS="-  I${BDB_PREFIX}/include/"

=========================================================
4: ./configure
5: make   (Wait to complete it ... .... )
6: sudo make install  (Optional)

 To check if Dogecoind is Installed and Running, Please run

 >> **dogecoind -daemon**
```

If you get this error:

```
 Error: To use dogecoind, or the -server option to dogecoin-qt, you must set an rpcpassword in the configuration file:
/root/.dogecoin/dogecoin.conf
It is recommended you use the following random password:
rpcuser= 'username' 
rpcpassword= 'userpassword'
(you do not need to remember this password)
The username and password MUST NOT be the same.
If the file does not exist, create it with owner-readable-only file     permissions.
It is also recommended to set alertnotify so you are notified of problems;
for example: alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "Dogecoin Alert" admin@foo.com
```

THEN create **dogecoin.conf** file in **./root/.dogecoin/** and paste following lines in it

```
rpcuser= 'username' 
rpcpassword= 'userpassword'
alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "Dogecoin Alert" youremail@gmail.com
--------------END---------------


 SAMPLE RESULTS AFTER Running 'make'

root@ateq:/home/rails/dogecoin# make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rails/dogecoin/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rails/dogecoin/src'
CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-hmac_sha512.lo
CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-ripemd160.lo
CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-scrypt.lo
CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha1.lo
CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha256.lo
CXX      crypto/libbitcoinconsensus_la-sha512.lo
```

.....................